# Why name of today widget in OSX is always "Widget"?

Tags: cocoa, xcode6, osx-yosemite, today-extension, notificationcenter

I am learning today-extension widget programming for OSX (not iOS currently). And I am trying to develop a calendar widget as a practice.

But the title or the name of the widget in notification center is always "Widget" instead of what I set.

I changed the value of "CFBundleDisplayName" in InfoPlist.strings of all locations (currently only Base and Simplified Chinese).

InfoPlist.strings (Base)

```
/* Display name and description for this extension. */
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "This Month";
"com.apple.notificationcenter.widget.description" = "Show calendar for this month";
```

InfoPlist.strings (Simplified Chinese)

```
/* Display name and description for this extension. */
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "本月";
"com.apple.notificationcenter.widget.description" = "显示本月月历";
```

Also, I changed the value of "Bundle display name" in Info.plist in Widget group which compile target is the Widget.

When I test the widget in Widget Simulator, its name is what I set in InfoPlist.strings. But when I compile (even clean & compile) and run the whole application, and then open the notification center, the name of my new widget is always "Widget".

According to the guide (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH5-SW6), the name of widget should be set in InfoPlist.strings and nowhere else is mentioned.

Did I miss some important setting file or anything wrong with the code?

The code could be found in https://github.com/programus/this-month

Comment: I tried that code and I cannot reproduce the problem you describe. The widget shows up in the notification center labeled "This Month".

Comment: So this mean the system stored some "cache" in which the name is "Widget" but I do not know how to clear the "cache"... Will it change if you modify the name to something else?

Comment: I restarted my system and re-run my app, and the name of the widget became what I set. Looks like the system will remember the name of every widget in memory. I still want to know whether there is a way to refresh the name without restart the whole system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just for reference this how I resolved the same issue.

Update Bundle Display Name to whatever you want

`Widget/InfoPlist.strings`

```
  "CFBundleDisplayName" = "My App";
```

Quit *XCode*.

Quit *Widget Simulator*.

Go into *Activity Monitor* app and quit `Notification Center` process name.

Notification Center will restart with updated Bundle Display Name.